# Inherited forms are jumbled in designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, designer

I have an inherited form that adds some objects to the base form. Hoewever, after I am done designing and close and re-open the designer on that form, a lot of objects are placed incorrectly, both location and size. This means I have to reposition a lot of objects each time I edit this form, which is quite annoying.

Before:

[image]

and after a simple save -> close -> open:

[image]

**Edit:** the problems seem to only be with items that are anchored on the right side or the bottom.

Comment: I suffered from the same issue and it was because Windows 8 had the DPI set to 125%. Once I set it back to the default of 100% the issue went away.

Comment: @Equalsk I am using Windows 7. Where is that DPI setting you are talking about?

Comment: [This is a good guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html) and saves me typing it out in a comment ;-)

Comment: Yes, this is an unpleasant problem with the Anchor property when you use visual inheritance.  It will anchor to the base form, not the derived form so the size will be wrong when you change the derived form size.  Extra nasty because it *seems* to work fine in the designer.  Until you run your app or re-open the form in the designer, then it jumps back to its original size.  If there's a simple workaround for it then it is a very well-kept secret.  You'll have to avoid the right/bottom anchor in a base form and use code.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. I removed the right/bottom anchor in my inherited form, and that seems to be good for now.